# Reading text file locally using javascript is not working without Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

I have an HTML file ( suppose "myHTML.html") and a  **local** text file from which I want to load content and attach it to myHTML.

My problem is that whenever I try to use this code:

```
    function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

which I've seen in a couple of threads here to read locally from text file, it works fine with VS-code and liveserver, but when I open myHtml directly with chrome without VS-code I get errors that say:

```
"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load", 

"Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https"

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"
```

Does anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: The solution is to use a server. You cannot make a GET request without a server because the server is what responds to a GET request. All you need is a basic Apache installation. (also, using `XMLHttpRequest` by definition isn't about opening local files, unless local means "on the same server")

Comment: The only way to actually read a local file is to use an `<input type="file">`, then manually select the file from the hard drive. Not what you want, I assume.

Comment: @ChrisG You assume right

Comment: @ChrisG What about loading the inner HTML of an external local html file to the current html file?

Comment: Doesn't matter if its HTML or txt or Egyptian hieroglyphs. You cannot do any of this with a flle directly opened in the browser. Just install Apache. (The only thing that will work is include a local `.js` file via `<script>` that appends text to the HTML doc)